# Copy Task ID from one list to another

Tags: list

I need to copy a Task ID (which is a number) from one list to another list.

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Please don't add your name or "Thanks" as a signature to posts. It adds unnecessary information and "noise" to the page that decreases its value.

Comment: Please also read [our FAQ on how to tag](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/how-do-i-use-tags-appropriately) (e.g. tag by feature not by version). If a tag you'd like to use is missing, simply flag a moderator. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variety of options, you can use lookup lists to allow users to specify the value.

You can use a workflow to do it.

You could use client side script, jQuery and SPServices, to do it.

Not knowing any details about the process, either of this would be feasible.  If the question is phrased with a little more detail, one option might be more desirable than the others.

Comment: Lookup looks a good option ... thx